# Скрыть дубликаты записей в SQL-запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server

Часть запроса:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      SYS.Name0 'PC',
      VC.Name0 'Video',
      WMIM.UserFriendlyName0 'Monitor',
      CASE DDISK.Index0
      WHEN '5' THEN '6' 
      WHEN '4' THEN '5'
      WHEN '3' THEN '4'
      WHEN '2' THEN '3'
      WHEN '1' THEN '2'
      WHEN '0' THEN '1'
      END '# HDD',
      DDISK.Caption0 'HDD'
FROM v_R_System SYS
      INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_Disk DDISK ON SYS.ResourceID = DDISK.ResourceID
      INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_Video_Controller VC ON SYS.ResourceID = VC.ResourceID
      INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_WMIMonitorID WMIM ON SYS.ResourceID = WMIM.ResourceID
```

Что я получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что необходимо получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно избавиться от дублирующих записей?

Comment: CASE DDISK.Index0
      WHEN '5' THEN '6' 
      WHEN '4' THEN '5'
      WHEN '3' THEN '4'
      WHEN '2' THEN '3'
      WHEN '1' THEN '2'
      WHEN '0' THEN '1'
      END
Шикарная конструкция. чем DDISK.Index0 + 1 не нравится?

Comment: Это НЕ ДУБЛИ. А сокрытие значения поля, если оно равно значению поля предыдущей при заданной сортировке записи, делают на клиенте. Ну в очень крайнем случае можно применить костыль типа `CASE WHEN field=LAG(field) THEN '' ELSE field END` - и готовиться к побиванию камнями...

Answer (score 1):

Как вам правильно намекнули в комментариях, оставлять в следующих строках пустое значение неверно - это нужно делать на клиенте. Но это, в первую очередь, относится к первой колонке, которая объединяет все значения, для остальных колонок, чтобы убрать лишние строки, надо джойнить не только по ResourceID, но и по порядковому номеру ресурса - так вы получите похожий на ваш набор.

Для этого вам необходимо получить максимальный порядковый номер ресурса, таблицу с цифрами от 1 до этого значения - для этого в примере я использовал функцию [getNums от Itzik Ben-Gan](http://tsql.solidq.com/SourceCodes/GetNums.txt), и потом присоединять левым джойном таблицы, в которые кроме идентификатора ресурса включен их порядковый номер.

В итоге у меня получился такой скрипт, у меня нет тестовых данных, чтобы его проверить, так что, возможно, я допустил синтаксические ошибки - надеюсь, вы сможете при необходимости их поправить:

```
SELECT 
      SYS.Name0 'PC',
      VC.Name0 'Video',
      WMIM.UserFriendlyName0 'Monitor',
      DDISK.Index0 + 1 '# HDD',
      DDISK.Caption0 'HDD'
FROM #v_R_System SYS
      outer apply (select max(cnt) as mx
                  from (select count(*) as cnt from v_GS_Disk 
                        where v_GS_Disk.ResourceID = Sys.ResourceId 
                        union all
                        select count(*) as cnt from v_GS_Video_Controller
                        where v_GS_Video_Controller.ResourceID = Sys.ResourceId 
                        union all
                        select count(*) as cnt from v_GS_WMIMonitorID
                        where v_GS_WMIMonitorID.ResourceID = Sys.ResourceId 
                        ) as cnts) as max_cnt
      cross apply dbo.GetNums(1, isnull(max_cnt.mx, 1)) as nums
      left  join (select ResourceId, Index0, Caption0
                       , row_number() over (partition by resourceId 
                                            order by Index0) as rn 
                  from dbo.v_GS_Disk DDISK) as DDISK
              on Sys.ResourceId = DDISK.ResourceId
              and nums.n = DDISK.rn
      left  join (select ResourceId, Name0
                       , row_number() over (partition by resourceId 
                                            order by Name0) as rn 
                  from dbo.v_GS_Video_Controller VC) as VC
              on Sys.ResourceId = VC.ResourceId
              and nums.n = VC.rn
      left  join (select ResourceId, UserFriendlyName0
                       , row_number() over (partition by resourceId 
                                            order by UserFriendlyName0) as rn 
                  from dbo.v_GS_WMIMonitorID WMIM) as WMIM
              on Sys.ResourceId = WMIM.ResourceId
              and nums.n = WMIM.rn
```

Comment: Запрос ссылается на недопустимое имя объекта "dbo.GetNums" и идентификатора nums.n.

Comment: Вы, простите, текст моего ответа целиком прочитали? Или просто скопировали код и выполнили его?

Comment: Просто скопировал код. К сожалению, я не совсем представляю какие действия я должен выполнить. Каким образом мне использовать функцию get.Nums?

Comment: по ссылке возьмите код функции и выполните в своей среде - у вас появится эта функция и вы сможете выполнить запрос.

Comment: Как в данном случае правильно использовать оператор WHERE с предикатом LIKE? В моём конкретном случае необходимо из запроса исключать много лишних устройств. Со скриптом выше он работает не правильно.

Comment: where используйте в подзапросе: left join (select ... from ... where ...) on ...

Comment: Получилось.
Остался крайний вопрос-результат запроса отображается несколько иначе, чем следует.
К примеру, есть PC с 7 HDD, 1 Monitor, 1 Video.
При выполнении запроса получается 8 строк вместо 7, первая из которых имеет пустые значения в столбцах, которые были описаны с GetNums, а последующие начинают перечисление HDD с 2 по 7.
8-ая строка имеет в себе запись о Video, HDD 1 и Monitor. Соответственно, вопрос в том, как исключить "лишнюю" строку и сделать правильное отображение, как на 2-ом скриншоте выше?

Comment: Ох что-то мне не верится в такое. Точно больше ничего не правили в запросе?

Comment: Ситуация, описанная выше, возникала из-за использования SELECT DISTINCT заместо SELECT.
При использовании SELECT, включая оператор WHERE, вместо того, чтобы убирать строки с исключенным значением из вывода, запрос их оставляет пустыми.
Как можно исправить эту ситуацию?

Comment: Какие строки оставляет пустыми? Я не понимаю, о чем вы пишете. Предлагаю вам сформулировать проблему отдельным вопросом, например, формат комментариев не очень удобен для этого.

Comment: К примеру, есть PC с 1 HDD, 1 Monitor, 2 Video. Одно из значений Video я исключаю в подзапросе, по принципу, описанному вами выше.
В итоге, запрос выдает те же две строки, что и без оператора WHERE, с разницей в том, что вторая строка, с исключенным значением, имеет значение NULL, вместо того, чтобы отсутствовать в принципе.

Comment: Приведите эту часть запроса, где исключаете одно значение video - всю часть с left join. Что-то тут не так - не должно быть лишних строк.

Comment: left join (select ResourceId, Name0
                       , row_number() over (partition by resourceId 
                                            order by Name0) as rn
    from dbo.v_GS_Video_Controller VC where VC.Name0 NOT LIKE '%Secondary%') as VC 
              on Sys.ResourceId = VC.ResourceId
              and nums.n = VC.rn

Comment: Все ок, не могу сказать, почему и как отображается отдельная строка. Все же стоит подробнее в новом вопросе расписать.