# Оператор WHERE не убирает строки в SQL-запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется следующий SQL-запрос:

```
   SELECT 
          SYS.Name0 'PC',
          VC.Name0 'Video',
          DDISK.Index0 + 1 '# HDD',
          DDISK.Caption0 'HDD'
    FROM v_R_System SYS
          outer apply (select max(cnt) as mx
                      from (select count(*) as cnt from v_GS_Disk 
                            where v_GS_Disk.ResourceID = Sys.ResourceId 
                            union all
                            select count(*) as cnt from v_GS_Video_Controller
                            where v_GS_Video_Controller.ResourceID = Sys.ResourceId 
                            ) as cnts) as max_cnt
          cross apply dbo.GetNums(1, isnull(max_cnt.mx, 1)) as nums
           left join (select ResourceId, Index0, Caption0
                           , row_number() over (partition by resourceId 
                                                order by Index0) as rn 
                      from dbo.v_GS_Disk DDISK where DDISK.InterfaceType0 != 'USB') as DDISK
                  on Sys.ResourceId = DDISK.ResourceId
                  and nums.n = DDISK.rn
           left join (select ResourceId, Name0
                           , row_number() over (partition by resourceId 
                                                order by Name0) as rn 
                      from dbo.v_GS_Video_Controller VC where vc.name0 not like '%lan%') as VC
                  on Sys.ResourceId = VC.ResourceId
                  and nums.n = VC.rn
```

В запросе используется два условия выборки.
Вместо исключения из вывода строк, не попадающих под выборку, запрос их оставляет пустыми и они остаются при выводе.

Пример вывода без выборки: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример вывода с выборкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае должно выводиться 2 строки.
Как, в данном случае, исправить запрос?

Comment: Заменить `left join` на обычный `join` или вынести условия в основной where запроса, или в крайнем случае проверить на НЕ NULL в where основного запроса

Comment: Спасибо. крайний вариант подошел.

Comment: Возможно ли объединить в WHERE несколько колонок на условие IS NOT NULL?

Comment: Да, возможно...

Comment: Прошу привести правильный синтаксис

Comment: конечно, пишите несколько условий с AND или OR в зависимости от требований. `a is not null AND b is not null`. Смотрю на ваш запрос и что то мне подсказывает, что первая часть с apply вообще не нужна, вторые два подзапроса вполне можно склеить между собой по full outer join (так же по RN или вообще через union со сдвигом колонок и группировкой) и все это вместе подклеить к основному

Comment: задача убрать пустые значения, если они пустые сразу в нескольких колонках одной строки. если хотя бы в одной колонке есть значение-строка не убирается. через AND это не работает.

Comment: оно не может не работать. вы уверены, что пишите условия в том where которое нужно. Обращаю ваше внимание, что в запросе приведенном в вашем вопросе вообще отсутствует нужна секция where, она должна быть после всего приведенного текста

Answer (score 0):

Теперь понял, в чем проблема.

Вам нужно продублировать условия выбора в подзапросе, присоединяемом через outer apply, чтобы выбирать количество только нужных записей, вот так:

```
SELECT 
          SYS.Name0 'PC',
          VC.Name0 'Video',
          DDISK.Index0 + 1 '# HDD',
          DDISK.Caption0 'HDD'
    FROM v_R_System SYS
          outer apply (select max(cnt) as mx
                      from (select count(*) as cnt from v_GS_Disk 
                            where v_GS_Disk.ResourceID = Sys.ResourceId 
                              and v_GS_Disk.InterfaceType0 != 'USB'
                            union all
                            select count(*) as cnt from v_GS_Video_Controller
                            where v_GS_Video_Controller.ResourceID = Sys.ResourceId 
                              and v_GS_Video_Controller.name0 not like '%lan%'
                            ) as cnts) as max_cnt
          cross apply dbo.GetNums(1, isnull(max_cnt.mx, 1)) as nums
           left join (select ResourceId, Index0, Caption0
                           , row_number() over (partition by resourceId 
                                                order by Index0) as rn 
                      from dbo.v_GS_Disk DDISK 
                      where DDISK.InterfaceType0 != 'USB') as DDISK
                  on Sys.ResourceId = DDISK.ResourceId
                  and nums.n = DDISK.rn
           left join (select ResourceId, Name0
                           , row_number() over (partition by resourceId 
                                                order by Name0) as rn 
                      from dbo.v_GS_Video_Controller VC 
                      where vc.name0 not like '%lan%') as VC
                  on Sys.ResourceId = VC.ResourceId
                  and nums.n = VC.rn
```

Comment: Приведите свой вариант, без apply. Если что, основная задача сформулирована в этом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670571

Comment: Ok, привел. в текущем вопросе

Comment: Ну, как бы, вариант ) Я только не очень люблю применение агрегатных функций к любым не числовым колонкам и не к датам, но в вашем варианте есть существенный плюс - таблицы и условия упоминаются только один раз, это может быть лучше с т.з. производительности.

Comment: Да тут везде и плюсы и минусы есть, если ТС захочет взять из SYS всего несколько записей, то сомневаюсь, что в моем варианте оптимизатор додумается использовать индексы по resourceId в остальных таблицах и в итоге они будут все равно просканированы полностью. В вашем варианте шансы на использование индекса выше при таком раскладе

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, должен ли я дублировать как-либо в подзапросе выражение типа CASE WHEN THEN ELSE для корректного вывода?

Comment: Я не вижу там такого выражения, поэтому не понимаю, для чего его дублировать.

Comment: в примере выше часть запроса. по предложенному вами принципу я присоединяю другие таблицы, в том числе, где используется выражение CASE WHEN THEN ELSE.

Comment: без четкого понимания, как именно он используется, могу сказать, что надо дублировать. В некоторых ситуациях может быть не надо, но такие ситуации надо разбирать отдельно.

Comment: Могли бы вы привести синтаксис для дублирования этого выражения в подзапросе?

Comment: К примеру, если в  подзапросе, присоединяемом через cross apply, это выглядит так:
     left join (select ResourceId, Name0
                             , row_number() over (partition by ResourceId
                                                             order by
                                                             case Name0 WHEN '1' THEN '2' END) as rn
from v_GS_Video_Controller) as VC
om SYS.ResourceID = VC.ResourceID
and nums.n = VC.rn

то, как это продублировать в подзапросе через outer apply?

Comment: Если case используется только для сортировки - не надо его дублировать. Дублировать нужно только условия фильтрации (чтобы правильно определить итоговое количество строк для каждого ResourceId)

Comment: В моём случае case используется для замены значений

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам нужно что то вроде этого:

```
SELECT SYS.Name0 'PC',
       MAX(X.Video) Video,
       MAX(X.Monitor) Monitor,
       MAX(X.Index0)+1 '# HDD'
       MAX(X.Caption0) 'HDD'
  FROM (
      SELECT ResourceID, Index0, Caption0, NULL as Video, NULL as Monitor,
             row_number() over(partition by resourceId order by NULL) as RN
        FROM dbo.v_GS_Disk
       WHERE InterfaceType0 != 'USB'
       UNION ALL
      SELECT ResourceID, NULL, NULL, Name0, NULL,
             row_number() over(partition by resourceId order by NULL)
        FROM dbo.v_GS_Video_Controller
       WHERE name0 not like '%lan%'
       UNION ALL
      SELECT ResourceID, NULL, NULL, NULL,UserFriendlyName0,
             row_number() over(partition by resourceId order by NULL)
        FROM dbo.v_GS_WMIMonitorID
  ) X
  JOIN v_R_System SYS on X.ResourceID=SYS.ResourceID
 GROUP BY X.ResourceID, X.RN, SYS.Name0
```